# Python - How to extract the name between two characters (> and <)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to build a scraper for Yelp and get the usernames from reviews.

Here is the code I have:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])

CHROMEDRIVER_PATH ='../Selenium/chromedriver.exe'
service = ChromeService(executable_path=CHROMEDRIVER_PATH)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
driver.get('https://www.yelp.com/biz/taste-of-texas-houston')
User = []
content = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
data = soup.findAll("li", attrs={'class':'margin-b5__09f24__pTvws border-color--default__09f24__NPAKY'})
for each in data:
    users = BeautifulSoup(str(each))
    names = users.find_all("a", attrs={'class':'css-1422juy' , "href": lambda L: L and L.startswith("/user_details?userid=")})
    for name in names:
        print(name)
```

which gives me output like this:

```
<a class="css-1422juy" href="/user_details?userid=70GQY6hu-iW2LZA6RoYXfw">Melissa G.</a>
<a class="css-1422juy" href="/user_details?userid=u766nLu7-4ptpYTPdlGbnA">Shannon B.</a>
<a class="css-1422juy" href="/user_details?userid=Icf-gy1YWYck0P3zW3f-pg">Jason Z.</a>
<a class="css-1422juy" href="/user_details?userid=m-BAEdY7IfKmXm5zk_XoLw">Marty H.</a>
<a class="css-1422juy" href="/user_details?userid=lbY_bZoZJwXNV7NiVAUr9w">Jules R.</a>
<a class="css-1422juy" href="/user_details?userid=aXCzU04l53gmgiQvISreaA">Christine H.</a>
<a class="css-1422juy" href="/user_details?userid=tbAN5YiUmBbccxdZAC4Daw">Tanisha K.</a>
<a class="css-1422juy" href="/user_details?userid=ZcG3eoa9mI_-CEgp5XagiQ">Steven T.</a>
<a class="css-1422juy" href="/user_details?userid=DZqA7lTwUsNUW8gF5dUjyw">Dan D.</a>
<a class="css-1422juy" href="/user_details?userid=e7xkB5I6BygG8yNX2URvgA">Ashley Y.</a>
```

Now, I am having a hard time getting the names out of these strings. I tried using several different methods to extract the name as a string between two characters > and < but I haven't had any luck.

here is what i tried:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])

CHROMEDRIVER_PATH ='../Selenium/chromedriver.exe'
service = ChromeService(executable_path=CHROMEDRIVER_PATH)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
driver.get('https://www.yelp.com/biz/taste-of-texas-houston')
User = []
content = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
data = soup.findAll("li", attrs={'class':'margin-b5__09f24__pTvws border-color--default__09f24__NPAKY'})
for each in data:
    users = BeautifulSoup(str(each))
    names = users.find_all("a", attrs={'class':'css-1422juy' , "href": lambda L: L and L.startswith("/user_details?userid=")})
    for name in names:
        start = name.find('>')
        end = name.find('<',start+1)
        substring = name.find[start+1:end]
        print(f"Start: {start}, End: {end}")
        print(substring)
```

But this doesn't work either.
Any suggestion on how to get these names out into the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to correct your code, problem is here:

```
    start = name.find('>')
    end = name.find('<',start+1)
    substring = name.find[start+1:end]
```

which needs to be changed to:

```
    namestr=str(name)
    start = namestr.find('>')
    end = namestr.find('<',start+1)
    substring = namestr[start+1:end]
```

to create a *slice* of string. Normally you should not use `str()` method, but it seems your data is not string. But you can use regular expression like what [Tim's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70231875/5529197) answer. Generally speaking, regular expressions can be slow if they are complex. So sometimes I just use something like yours.

**Update:**

I tried a simplified version of your code and it works for me. Here is that code:

```
names = ['<a class="css-1422juy" href="/user_details?userid=70GQY6hu-iW2LZA6RoYXfw">Melissa G.</a>',
'<a class="css-1422juy" href="/user_details?userid=u766nLu7-4ptpYTPdlGbnA">Shannon B.</a>',
'<a class="css-1422juy" href="/user_details?userid=Icf-gy1YWYck0P3zW3f-pg">Jason Z.</a>',
'<a class="css-1422juy" href="/user_details?userid=m-BAEdY7IfKmXm5zk_XoLw">Marty H.</a>',
'<a class="css-1422juy" href="/user_details?userid=lbY_bZoZJwXNV7NiVAUr9w">Jules R.</a>',
'<a class="css-1422juy" href="/user_details?userid=aXCzU04l53gmgiQvISreaA">Christine H.</a>',
'<a class="css-1422juy" href="/user_details?userid=tbAN5YiUmBbccxdZAC4Daw">Tanisha K.</a>',
'<a class="css-1422juy" href="/user_details?userid=ZcG3eoa9mI_-CEgp5XagiQ">Steven T.</a>',
'<a class="css-1422juy" href="/user_details?userid=DZqA7lTwUsNUW8gF5dUjyw">Dan D.</a>',
'<a class="css-1422juy" href="/user_details?userid=e7xkB5I6BygG8yNX2URvgA">Ashley Y.</a>']

for name in names:
    namestr=str(name)
    start = namestr.find('>')
    end = namestr.find('<',start+1)
    substring = namestr[start+1:end]
    print(f"Start: {start}, End: {end}")
    print(substring)
```

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen I tried that and i am still getting an error:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Comment: @Slavisha84 I'm trying a simplified version of your code and it works for me....

Comment: @Slavisha84 I added what I tested which works.

Comment: @Slavisha84 probably name is not *string*. try updated code which uses `str()` first.

Comment: I managed to make this work with the code you and Tim did together. Thank you both.

Answer (score 0):

Simply Use this

```
s='<a class="css-1422juy" href="/user_details?userid=70GQY6hu-iW2LZA6RoYXfw">Melissa G.</a>'
Username = s[s.find('">')+len('">'):s.find('</a>')]
```

Comment: @Afshin - I am literally pasting your code and replacing my code appropriately and I am still getting an error message. Can you try your solution on my entire code and see if it works for you?